# How to test BigDecimal values

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, bigdecimal

I am trying to unit test some methods producing BigDecimal outputs but I am quite confused with the varying precissio:

```
assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(20), result);
```

I recently switched from crating BigDecimal values using constructor (`new BigDecimal(value)` to using `valueOf(value)`) and my tests are complaining:

```
Expected :20
Actual   :20.00
```

Setting `BigDecimal.valueOf(20.00)` is not helping so my question is, what is the correct way to test these floating point BigDecimal instances? Most of my test cases will have zeros after the floating point.

Comment: You could also try `assertTrue(BigDecimal.valueOf(20).compareTo(result) == 0)` or normalize both values before comparing by calling `result.stripTrailingZeros()` etc.

Comment: @Thomas That works if you don't care about precision, but if you actually want to assert that the value is exact then the only thing you can do is fix the value you expect.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's true but I'd assume the OP doesn't care about precision (and to be honest, I normally don't care about precision as well - in almost all cases I encountered 2 and 2.0000 are meant to be the same value).

Comment: May be helpful https://github.com/mortezaadi/bigdecimal-utils/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that [`BigDecimal.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) follows this rule:

> Compares this `BigDecimal` with the specified `Object` for equality.
>   Unlike `compareTo`, this method considers two `BigDecimal` objects
>   equal only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal
>   to 2.00 when compared by this method).

And `20` and `20.00` don't have the same scale.

You need to use either

```
new BigDecimal("20.00")
```

or

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(20).setScale(2)
```

or, if you like more esoteric options

```
BigDecimal.valueof(2000, 2)
```

The problem with `BigDecimal.valueOf(20.00)` is that following the rules of [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-), this results in a BigDecimal of `20.0` (that is, scale 1), and - slightly different - `new BigDecimal(20.00)` will result in a `BigDecimal` of `20` (scale 0).

Answer (score 3):

Besides the technical `new BigDecimal("20.00")` isn't the same as 
`new BigDecimal(20.00)` (because of the "" which trigger "string parsing"), I suggest you look into hamcrest.

That framework even offers [BigDecimalCloseTo](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/BigDecimalCloseTo.html) when you need to test "equality + delta", to be used like:

```
assertThat(new BigDecimal("1.03"), is(closeTo(new BigDecimal("1.0"), new BigDecimal("0.03"))))
```